# Mouse event listener, allow propagation up till document

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I have added a mouse event listener to block clicks:

```
window.addEventListener("mousedown", myMouseDown, true);

function myMouseDown(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

But this blocks even the chrome level click. Which is expected. How can I allow bubbling up till the `browser` element. I don't want the click going into the `contentWindow`. I know I can add to a bunch of event listeners to all the documents loaded but I want to do it with one listener above, hopefully learn something about bubbling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the event to the actual `contentWindow` (or `browser`) and stop it there.

Of course, this will still not allow the event to bubble down again, i.e. it will prevent the [Bubbling Phase](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) and Target Phase.

Comment: Oh dang thats the only way, so like `gBrowser.addEventListener` huh? I'll test it out, the thing is i want the autoscroll popup to work even tho clicks blokd

Comment: I tried adding to `gBrowser` it blocks the autoscroll popup panel. So then I added to the anon element holding the panel `notificationbox`'s: `var el = document.getAnonymousElementByAttribute(document.querySelector('#content'), 'class', 'plain');
Services.ww.activeWindow.alert(el.nodeName);` its still blocking the autoscroll pop upanel :(